# MySQL Help: SELECT table2.id WHERE ... table1.date is largest

Tags: sql, count, max

I have 2 tables, using an inner join to query them.

```
SELECT COUNT(table2.id) 
FROM table2 
INNER JOIN table1 ON table2.relazioneid = table1.id 
WHERE table1.date > ? AND table1.date < ?
```

It counts the ids of entries on reports between 2 dates. Table 1 holds info on the reports (date, groupid etc), table2 holds the entries on the reports.

I'd like to make a query almost exactly the same, except it only selects the ids from the report with the latest date, between those 2 dates.

Can anyone help? I can't quite get my head around MAX(date) type queries - all I get back is a count of every id and also the max date, rather than just those ids from the max date.

Thanks,

---

I've been thinking perhaps a nested SQL query - can you do this? I can find references on Google, but can't get it to work... Something similar to:

```
SELECT COUNT(table2.id) 
FROM table2 
INNER JOIN table1 ON table2.relazioneid = table1.id 
WHERE table1.date > ? AND table1.date < ? AND 
(
    SELECT MAX(date) 
    FROM table1 
    WHERE date > ? AND date < ?
)
```

Can't get that to work though, and when I try to test it in phpMyAdmin, it kicks me out with an error telling me my user doesn't have SELECT privileges. Strange, since this is a test server I'm logged into as root.

Comment: Can you provide the structure of both tables and exactly what information you want to retrieve from both tables? This will make it much simpler to provide valid sample code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without further information regarding the structure of the tables, I would suggest that you try something like this:

```
SELECT t2.id
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.relation_id
WHERE t1.date BETWEEN ? AND ?
HAVING MAX(t1.date)
```

I haven't tested this but it should point in one direction you could go with this problem. Your other suggestion of using a subquery is valid and might work something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM table2 t2 
WHERE t2.parent_id IN (
    SELECT t1.relation_id
    FROM table1 t1
    WHERE t1.date BETWEEN ? AND ?
    GROUP BY t1.relation_id
    HAVING MAX(t1.date)
)
```

Or in a join to a temporary table:

```
SELECT *
FROM table2 t2
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT t1.relation_id
    FROM table1 t1
    WHERE t1.date BETWEEN ? AND ?
    GROUP BY t1.relation_id
    HAVING MAX(t1.date)
) AS t1 ON t2.relation_id = t1.relation_id
```

Comment: Thanks. Got the nested select working - the actual query is significantly longer than the example I posted, and I'd got a typo.

Answer (score -1):

```
 ...WHERE table1.date BETWEEN'2009-01-01' AND '2009-01-02' ORDER BY table1.date LIMIT 10
```

will get you 10 first rows with the dates

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for - I need to get that latest date and select all the ids with that date.

Comment: That's not an answer, but a comment. Besides, it is MySql syntax.